# Is there an quick and easy way to find out which site I started my association bonus?

Tags: support, association

Just curious... but is there a way to find out which site I first got my association bonus from?

So, in other words, which site did I get 200 rep on first?

Just curious... :) Because I can't remember! :(

---

(The hard way would be to go through each of the sites I've signed up to (I could probably narrow it down a bit to see which ones it must have been through) and check the reputation tab and go to the time where I had around 200 rep... :/)

Comment: How could you forget your first SE site?

Comment: @angussidney I didn't... My first SE site was SO, but that doesn't necessarily mean that is the site I got 200 rep on first (as proven in Shadow's answer)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not super quick, but usually simple enough is via the [network profile reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation).

Hovering from the beginning, it's quite easy to find you got the bonus on May 6, 2014:

> [image] [image]

Now, since on both SO and SR you got round +100, it makes sense the bonus has been triggered on SU. Looking on your reputation tab on Super User for May 6, 2014 shows something weird:

> [image]

<s>Since on both SO and SR you got only the bonus, you must have gotten first to 200 on SU and the post giving you the reputation (+40) has been removed since then.</s>

Edit: turns out, I was mistaken! Your case is really special. Ticking the "all accounts" in the Network Reputation Graph show your [Ask Different account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/76905), which is the absolute winner:

> [image]

Comment: There go *my* analysis and answer ;)

Comment: Nice! :) That's great! Thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: @Oded lol, but I was mistaken after all... correcting answer now. :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ cheers, see edit for correct answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what..!? lol. Thanks for double checking (and correcting!) :) And yeah... *I* am pretty special... :P